# Custom Android MMS/SMS application from source code?

Tags: android, sms, mms

Okay here's the deal:

I want to download the full source of the MMS/SMS application that ships with Android phones.  I want to be able to modify it, and add a little custom functionality to it.

I am developing using Eclipse, and I'm on Windows 7.  I have noticed that there is now a Git for Windows, but I am pretty lost in it and not sure how to integrate everything with Eclipse.

Basically, I want to just get it to the point where I have all the source code visible in Eclipse and be able to see the app run JUST like the built-in texting/MMS app that is already on my phone.  Then I'll know that I can modify it and proceed.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's a mirror of the SMS/MMS app on GitHub [here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms). Just import that to Eclipse and customise away.

Comment: I think the devil is in the details.  I appreciate your comment, because it did get me a lot closer.  I had not previously realized that there was an Import --> Git option in Eclipse.

However, I have another issue.  What options do I choose?  I chose to create a new project.  Also on the "branches" selection, I picked everything involving gingerbread and master, and tools.  Is this correct?

Comment: There are tons of missing libraries.  I was given the impression that the texting app is built into the firmware, and thus you cannot customize it... even though the code is available...  But not *all* the code is available.  The libraries are not.

Comment: To customize (and then get it working!) you need to download all of AOSP and then build which is a huge amount of work

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to customize and use it only on your own phone (without publishing), this is not a good idea. This is because it uses classes that are hidden from the sdk. By default you won't even be able to build the apk via eclipse, but there is a [way](http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/). The reason why this is a bad idea is that the hidden apis are not guaranteed to remain the same through different api-levels and your app can stop working with the next android update, and might also not work on previous api-levels. In-fact your app might not even work on selected phones running the same api-level.